# How to insert many records excluding some in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to create a table with a subset of records from a master table.
for example, I have:

```
id  name   code  ref
1   peter  73    2.5
2   carl   84    3.6
3   jack   73    1.1
```

I want to store peter and carl but not jack because has same peter's code.
I need the max ref!

I try this:

```
SELECT id, name, DISTINCT(code) INTO new_tab
FROM old_tab 
WHERE (conditions)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.code, t.ref
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by ref desc) as seqnum
      from old_tab t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The insert statement just wraps `insert` around this:

```
insert into new_tab(id, name, code)
    select t.id, t.name, t.code
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by code order by ref desc) as seqnum
          from old_tab t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Why you use row_number() function?

Comment: @Mrslipp3ry Does it make more sense if you think of `row_number` as if it was `rank()` or `dense_rank()`? It doesn't matter, since all of them start with `1`...

Answer (score 3):

You can try a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT ot.* FROM old_tab ot
JOIN
(
   SELECT "code", MAX("ref") AS "MaxRef"
   FROM old_tab
   GROUP BY "code"
) tbl
ON ot."code" = tbl."code"
AND ot."ref" = tbl."MaxRef"
```

Output:

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ CODE ║ REF ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ peter ║   73 ║ 2.5 ║
║  2 ║ carl  ║   84 ║ 3.6 ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╩═════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9307b/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code) id, name, code
FROM old_tab
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY code, ref DESC
```

Comment: I think you missed an essential part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Correct query

Since you `need the max ref!` the *correct* form for `DISTINCT ON` would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code)
       id, name, code
FROM   old_tab
WHERE  (conditions)
ORDER  BY code, ref DESC
```

This is generally faster, simpler and shorter than solutions with a subquery and window function or aggregate functions.
If there can be multiple rows sharing the highest `ref`, add more `ORDER BY` items as tiebrekaer to decide which row to return. Or Postgres will pick an arbitrary one, since `DISTINCT ON` always returns a **single row** per `DISTINCT` expression.

Explanation, links and a benchmark comparing these styles in this closely related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Another fast way would be:

```
SELECT id, name, code, ref
FROM   old_tab t
WHERE  (conditions)
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   old_tab t2
   WHERE  (conditions)
   AND    t2.code = t.code
   AND    t2.ref > t.ref
   )
```

The **small difference**: this one does not break ties. If multiple rows per `code` (and `conditions`) share the highest `ref`, multiple rows will be returned.

#### `CREATE TABLE AS`

And for creating a new table from a `SELECT`, the recommended form is `CREATE TABLE AS`. Quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html):

> This command is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`, but **it is
>   preferred** since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of
>   the `SELECT INTO` syntax. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS` offers a superset
>   of the functionality offered by `SELECT INTO`.

Bold emphasis mine.
So use:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tab AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code)
       id, name, code
FROM   old_tab
WHERE  (conditions)
ORDER  BY code, ref DESC;
```